# /bin/login not working when run on console as root user

Tags: login, root, pam

when login command is executed it doesn't accepts root login , here the log of my console is copied once see it and helps me. But succeeds using another user ( sai ) .

```
root@sai:~# login

sai login: root

Login incorrect

sai login: sai

Password: 
Last login: Thu Jan  5 11:25:38 IST 2017 on pts/28
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-103-generic x86_64)

 ########* Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
          inet addr:192.168.2.198  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet addr:172.16.201.1  Bcast:172.16.201.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet addr:192.168.206.1  Bcast:192.168.206.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

391 packages can be updated.
50 updates are security updates.

sai@sai:~$
```

anyone please explain what's happening here ?

Comment: Have you set a root password?

Comment: yes. once observe 1 st line **root@sai:~#**  got the root access after setting the root password only.

Comment: That's no guarantee of a password (`sudo -i` and `sudo su -` get you root prompt on default Ubuntu without a root password). Are you running this via SSH or in a graphical terminal?

Comment: Why, at all, run 'login' from a terminal-root-prompt ?

Comment: NO. In terminal only i am running this. @muru

Comment: Login is configured from busybox using linux-pam dependencies through Buildroot for secure login . Then ported to my board,  when login to device it shows invalid login. But without linux-pam dependencies login is working Fine in Atmel board. so To test login behavior  in my ubuntu PC, run the /bin/login  but same behavior executes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

configure login source file in busybox source as to take rules from file with name `<service-name>` and compile, then write the configuration or rules in file `/etc/pam.d/<service_name>`. I added configuration settings to that file. Then it is Working Fine.

refer this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-pam-to-configure-authentication-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps for more information.

Thanks for the comments.

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Answer (score 2):

This is because `login`'s PAM configuration includes `pam_securetty` in Ubuntu:

```
$ grep pam_secure /etc/pam.d -R
/etc/pam.d/login:auth [success=ok new_authtok_reqd=ok ignore=ignore user_unknown=bad default=die] pam_securetty.so
```

And `/etc/securetty` does not include any pseudo-terminals:

```
$ grep pts /etc/securetty
# Technology Concepts serial card
```

Either add `pts/N` devices to `/etc/securetty`, or remove `pam_securetty` from `login`'s PAM configuration.